# Prepared statement with some where condition in case of any value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have prepared statement like

```
select * from books where author = ? and theme = ?
```

and i cant figure out what to do, if user select option "any author" or "any theme", what should i set to prepared statement?

Comment: You can pass more parameters for author condicion, for ej : if the user select any author then select * from books where  (0 = any or author = ? ); then any value must be 0, and the select query get all author, else user select and author, then any value must be 1 and the query take the or condition. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I dont get what you exactly mean.
I should use something like 
statement.setInt(1, authorId);
so i dont understand how i can pass more values.

Comment: Ok, any can be another param as author. select * from books where (0 = ? or author = ? ); and in your code  if(author.isAny()) pass 0 or 1 to first param and empty in second param,

Comment: I get you, but i think its bad solution, because it some kind of bad architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for "dynamic SQL". You can do it manually, or use an ORM.

Let's see the manual case:

```
String sql;
if (author == null) {
  if (theme == null) {
     sql = "select * from books";
  } else {
     sql = "select * from books where theme = ?";
  }
} else {
  if (theme == null) {
     sql = "select * from books where author = ?";
  } else {
     sql = "select * from books where author = ? and theme = ?";
  }
}
PreparedStatement ps = con.createStatement(sql);
int param = 1;
if (author != null) {
  ps.setString(param++, author);
}
if (theme != null) {
  ps.setString(param++, theme);
}
// The rest is just running the SQL and read the ResultSet.
```

Now, if you have 10 parameters, an ORM really helps a lot. Pretty much all of them support dynamic SQL in a really nice way.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, yeah, this is the option.

Answer (score 1):

Which parts of the SQL statement should be present is not covered by prepared statements (unless you get creative). Typically the solution is generating the conditions in the `where` clause dynamically, for example:

```
String sql = "select * from books where 1=1";
if (author != null) { 
    sql += " and author=?";
}
if (theme != null) { 
    sql += " and theme=?";
}
```

After you've prepared the statement, you need to set the parameters, taking care of using the right indexes:

```
int parameterIndex = 1;
if (author != null) {
    preparedStatement.setString(parameterIndex, author);
    parameterIndex++;
}
if (theme != null) {
    preparedStatement.setString(parameterIndex, theme);
    parameterIndex++;
}
```

Comment: I dont use concatenation, only prepared statements, you know, security stuff.

Comment: use concatenation to build the sql for the prepared statement from fixed constant pieces, *don't* use it to populate parameters. What are you going to do otherwise, write 2^N queries for N parameters that may be optional?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I dont get you first, you right, i can build prepared statement according to input params before use it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using 4 different prepared statements according to input data.

Comment: hmm... Aren't rhere **four** cases instead of three?

Comment: One case, when any author and any theme i have before, so i dont count this, but you right, there are 4 cases.